# Is there a way to disable the A button "bubble" when you are the only player currently alive?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-wii

My kids and I love playing New Super Mario Bros on the Wii in multiplayer mode. However, they tend to panic and using the A button to "bubble" when it's not necessary.

Normally this isn't a problem. However, if one of them is the only player currently alive and uses a bubble, we instantly lose the stage.

Is there an in-game setting or other way to prevent the only active player from using the bubble?  I assume the answer is No but I am hopeful that there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  That is not a configurable setting.  Any players in a bubble when the level ends will not lose a life, though you will have to restart the level from the beginning (or the checkpoint if you got it already).

If you're having trouble with gaming over, my friends and I found a way to get many lives for all players quickly.  In world 2-2, you can **grab the checkpoint**, then fall into the **sand pit** directly left of the flag.  This will lead you to a secret area that fills with coins when you hit the 'P' block.  There are enough coins in this area for each player to grab around 100 (depending on spacing).  When you get 100 coins in multiplayer mode, each player gets a life, so this should earn you around N lives for each player where N is the number of players.  You can then bubble (which loses no lives) and repeat this process from the checkpoint flag which is right next to the secret.

Comment: Thanks. The additional tip about coins in 2-2 is also helpful but we are waaaaay past the point of worrying about game over on this particular file :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry :( , that's programmed into the game. You can't change it without hacking. I would try to use a screwdriver and break the A button. lol, just kidding. Practice levels without pressing the A button, I guess...

Comment: And how would one go about practicing? Would you be able to elaborate on that?

Comment: @Texenox Play the game and don't hit the A button at all.

Comment: @Seiyria Well, that much I had figured.